# Need to apply AND logic in jquery each function for filtering functionality

Tags: javascript, filter

I want to implement a multiple filtering functionality in my website. I am having issue with obtaining correct functionality so I would be grateful if I could get help on achieving the correct functionality on applyFilter() function.

SCENARIO: User clicks on single storey, 3 bedrooms, 2 bathrooms buttons in the filter.

EXPECTED: Only products with single-storey having 3 bedrooms and 2 bathrooms should display (AND LOGIC).

CURRENT OP: It display all single-storey, all 3 bedrooms and all 2 bathrooms products (OR LOGIC).

```
    $( document ).ready( function ()
{
    var $filters = $( '.works-filter' ); // find the filters
    var $works = $( '.workItem' ); // find the portfolio items
    var showAll = $( '.showAll' ); // identify the "show all" button

    var cFilter, cFilterData; // declare a variable to store the filter and one for the data to filter by
    var filtersActive = []; // an array to store the active filters

    $filters.click( function ()
    { // if filters are clicked
        cFilter = $( this );
        cFilterData = cFilter.attr( 'data-filter' ); // read filter value

        highlightFilter();
        applyFilter();
        checkIfNoResults();
    } );


    function highlightFilter ()
    {
        var filterClass = 'works-filter-active';
        if ( cFilter.hasClass( filterClass ) )
        {
            cFilter.removeClass( filterClass );
            removeActiveFilter( cFilterData );
        } else if ( cFilter.hasClass( 'showAll' ) )
        {
            $filters.removeClass( filterClass );
            filtersActive = []; // clear the array
            cFilter.addClass( filterClass );
        } else
        {
            showAll.removeClass( filterClass );
            cFilter.addClass( filterClass );
            filtersActive.push( cFilterData );
        }
    }

    function applyFilter ()
    {
        // go through all portfolio items and hide/show as necessary
        $works.each( function ()
        {
            var i;
            var classes = $( this ).attr( 'class' ).split( ' ' );
            if ( cFilter.hasClass( 'showAll' ) || filtersActive.length == 0 )
            { // makes sure we catch the array when its empty and revert to the default of showing all items
                $works.addClass( 'show-workItem' ); //show them all
            } else
            {
                $( this ).removeClass( 'show-workItem' );
                for ( i = 0; i < classes.length; i++ )
                {
                    if ( filtersActive.indexOf( classes[ i ] ) > -1 )
                    {
                        $( this ).addClass( 'show-workItem' );
                    }

                }
            }
        } );

    }

    // remove deselected filters from the ActiveFilter array
    function removeActiveFilter ( item )
    {
        var index = filtersActive.indexOf( item );
        if ( index > -1 )
        {
            filtersActive.splice( index, 1 );
        }
    }

} );
```

Filter button demo code

```
        <div class="filter-button">
            <label class="checkWrap">
                <input type="checkbox" data-filter="<?php echo $storey->slug ?>" class=" works-filter
                                storeyCheck control" name="storeys" value="<?php echo $storey->slug ?>">
                <span class="check-span checkmark"> <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . $img; ?>"
                        class="p-5"><?php echo $storey->name; ?>
                </span>
            </label>
        </div>
```

Container demo code

```
 <div id="projects" class="workItem show-workItem mix <?php echo $storey->slug;?>">
       <div class="project-grid ">
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems that you found the problem. The link works as expected

Answer (score 0):

I used "every" and "includes" function to check compare two arrays.

```
 let checker = ( arr, target ) => target.every( v => arr.includes( v ) );

                for ( i = 0; i < classes.length; i++ )
                {
                    if ( checker( classes, filtersActive ) == true)
                    {
                        $( this ).addClass( 'show-workItem' );
                    }

                }
```